# Face Detection Library with C/C++ interface

Tags: c++, c, face-detection

Can you please point me to library(ies) for face detection (NO RECOGNITION NEEDED!)?
Any good-working libraries except OpenCV(!!!). 
Preferably free of charge - open source is not required.

Comment: Again what is the problem with opencv. I found it to be a pretty fast and reliable tool that worked well with few configurations steps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What bothers you about OpenCV? Their API or something else?

There is [libface](http://libface.sourceforge.net/file/Home.html) which is an opencv wrapper for face detection and recognition.

Comment: We've been using OpenCV for a long time but now for some license reasons (the CEO didnt provide me with exact information) I should find some alternatives. I know that OpenCV is very powerful and convinient SDK but I would like to know if there are any other good solutions.